# Can a variable be passed to an apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

In a recent answer I made an assumption that a variable could be passed to an `<apex:repeat>`. Once I went back and tested I was unable to do this and now I would like to ask the massed knowledge of SFSE if there is a solution to this?

**Question:**
Is there a way to pass a variable into the get function used in an `<apex:repeat value="{!myFunction}" var="myOutputVar">`

Reference:
[Splitting up an apex:repeat alphabetically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/splitting-up-an-apexrepeat-alphabetically/1504)

Comment: I think in general it's not possible to pass an argument to a getter. A possible workaround would be to pass it through the URL or with an `apex:param` tag (and then retrieve it from the page parameters in the getter), but I know that it is not possible to use such a tag inside an `apex:repeat`.

Comment: I would suggest as a best practice to use <apex:param> than passing through url since I have seen browsers like IE having URL limits of 2000 characters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a value to a getter.

In the past I did some research in this area and it seems getter methods get executed exactly once and are then cached in the background so if your VF page calls the same getter twice, it will simply receive the data from the first execution and the getter code will not be executed again.

Comment: If you change the value and rerender the apex:repeat, it will re-execute and return a different value.